# How to make my discord.py bot only allow @everyone and @here from only admins and mods and not from normal members

Tags: discord.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands 

bot = discord.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=False)
async def delmessage(message):
 await message.delete()
```

Comment: Disable the @ everyone & @ here permissions in the settings for the channels in your server & only enable it for admins & mods

Answer (score 0):

As explained by [stijndcl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13568999/stijndcl) in comment, the best solution is to go directly in your server settings to allow only admins and moderators to use `@everyone` and `@here`.

If you still you want to use a bot, something can easily be done using the `on_message` handler and then checking the roles of the message author to delete or keep the message.

The problem with this method is that the filtering process is done **after** the message publication, so deleting an unauthorized ping will create [ghost pings](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Ghost%20Ping) and therefore a poor experience for your server members (and again why bother when a setting exists for this exact purpose).